# Neopixel with raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-4, raspberry-pi-os

I am using a neopixel for my raspberry pi project. I am trying to control 30 pixels and the strip is 20cm long. Can I use it just by using the pi's 5v pin? Also if I it is possible, how long should the wires which connect my raspberry pi and the neopixel be?

Comment: 30 neopixels * 60mah max per pixel is _1800 mah_. Probably not a good idea. Even if you only did half brightness for all of them that'd still be 900mah.

Comment: And its actually 100% (1800mA) during 50% of the time, so 900mA is a wrong statement. But your right it is a BAD idea to use the Pi's 5volt to power the NeoPixels.

Answer (score 0):

The 5V Pin is directly connected to the USB Input, so basically you could draw as much current as the Power supply can provide minus the current draw from the Pi.
But consider that it has to go through the PCB Coppertraces so if you draw to much you will grill your Pi.
Generally speaking, it's a better idea to power Circuits (especially ones who draw more current) via a separate Power supply.
Here is the Guide from adafruit about how to wire it properly: https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-wiring

The Wirelength doesn't really matter. I tested the neopixels with a bit more than 5 meters of cable between the Pi and the strip so that should be plenty.